# How do i setState onClick

Tags: reactjs, state, infinite-loop

Hi so i got my react function with a state that i use to know which componont should be rendered at a given time; here is my main App Function (i only include the function not the rest of class since it is not relevent)

My app function

```
function App(){
  const [menuState, setMenuState] = useState('journal');
  
  return(
    <>
      <button onClick={setMenuState('journal')}>JOUNRAL</button>
      <button onClick={setMenuState('stats')}>STATS</button>
      <MenuHandler menu={menuState}/>
    </>
  );
}
```

My MenuHandler function

```
function MenuHandler(props) {
  const menu = props.menu;
  if(menu==="journal")
    return (<Journal />);
  if(menu==="stats")
    return (<Stats />);
  return (<Journal />);
}
```

When i do this i get an infinite loop and i can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `setMenuState` on each render, therefore the infinite loop. You are not assigning it to the `onClick` handler, pass an arrow function like this to solve it:

```
<button onClick={() => setMenuState('journal')}>JOUNRAL</button>
<button onClick={() => setMenuState('stats')}>STATS</button>
```